# write div element id in cshtml using mvc5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I attempt to show google map in my view. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Initialize();
    function Initialize() {
        google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
        var Tunisie = new google.maps.LatLng(36.81881, 10.16596);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: Tunisie,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.81881, 10.16596);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Tate Gallery'
        });
        marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
});
```

Currently, this javascript is placed in index view. I want to apply this javascript in a div element with id `map_canvas`. I use div element with id `map_canvas` in this cshtml but it shows nothing...

Where can I use div element?

Comment: Are you referencing google? <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[your key here]"></script>

Comment: i use this:
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
and i figure theres nothing wrong in div element....whats wrong in this javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your:

```
<script src="maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"; type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" ; type="text/javascript"></script>
```

EDIT:

This is the exact code I have in a test project:

Index.cshtml:

```
<style>
#map_canvas{
        margin-top: 50px;
        height: 250px;
    }
</style>

@section Scripts{
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" ; type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Initialize();
        function Initialize() {
            google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
            var Tunisie = new google.maps.LatLng(36.81881, 10.16596);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: Tunisie,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.81881, 10.16596);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Tate Gallery'
            });
            marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: i also try this but it shows : Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError . 
when i use this: 
<script type="text/javascript" src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAOPBWkkuQyk_w0CU7FMXzSKqNhZXTk9Xg"> </script>
it shows google map undefined.
i am hopeless.

Comment: yes i was include that...this is a typo...sorry for that